# "voting corrected" does not give the up votes back

Tags: discussion, support, downvotes, serial-voting

Someone continuously downvoted all my posts in a small interval of time. I got the reputation back in 24 hours, but the down votes are still affecting the scores of my posts.

Will the proper scores return? If not it doesn't seem like the voting is corrected despite what it says.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: I get back the votes from corrected serial downvoting about 40% of the time (and this isn't to do with caching).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

That's because post scores are cached, and for whatever reason the cache isn't flushed immediately after a voting correction, giving the false impression that the votes weren't really reverted even though the reputation changes were. Many serial downvoters do what they do with the intention of making a dent in someone's reputation, but what hurts more IMO is the effect on the post scores, since scores affect sorting in Q&A by default. Considering the system actually makes it a point to recalculate your reputation after a voting correction (which is why the rep change is effective immediately), I don't see why it doesn't do the same with post scores.

If you had enough reputation, you would be able to click your post scores and [show the vote counts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user), which would force a reload of the counts. But you don't, so I've gone ahead and refreshed the score of each of your affected posts for you. This would not be the first time — I've done the same for other users affected by serial votes (up or down), and I've certainly done the same for my own posts.

(I've also warned the user who downvoted your posts, in case you're worried about that.)

Comment: is it automatically change?

Comment: @dream hunter: The scores should automatically update... eventually... I'm guessing after a day or two. But I think that's stupid and you shouldn't have to wait, which is why I went and reloaded the vote counts for you.

Comment: Perhaps this is a good time to add a batch process that runs at a set time every x hours to do this?

Comment: @cybermonkey: There already is one, it just doesn't run at a very good time of day I think. I'm not even sure it runs every day.

Comment: @BoltClock how do you warn user? How is he notified?

Comment: As for why it doesn't happen instantly: might it be because it's too resource-intensive on the SQL side (thus the need to fix the batch process)?

Comment: @xenteros I imagine the moderators are able to see who is responsible for serial voting if the said voting is automatically reversed.

Comment: The system corrects all scores in the entire database in a process that runs daily at midnight UTC.

Comment: @animuson: Maybe that should be moved to "shortly after voting correction" from "shortly before."

Comment: @animuson In theory it does. But that algorithm has a very low batting average. I'd guestimate that the algorithm alone works 20% of the time. Algorithm plus an email via the "contact us" link works 40-50% of the time.

Comment: @Hack-R Huh? I'm talking about a completely separate process. All the midnight one does is literally look at all votes in the database and rewrites the score for every single post. The vote invalidation script runs at 03:00 UTC.

Comment: Is there any attempt to fix this without a manual intervention by the affected person? I have a related [question here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335785/reversal-of-serial-voting-still-showing-as-negative-until-i-expand-voting-on-ind)

Comment: @Liam: Not that I'm aware of. The devs seem intent on keeping this by design.

Comment: Makes it kind of difficult for those of use who have had 67 questions downvoted multiple times over multiple days!

Comment: I have my some questions are still down voted.