# Using 'see vote counts' changed the counts

Tags: bug, upvotes, vote-count

I've tried to check my 'see vote counts' privilege on [Rotating per packets receiving by TCPDUMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39323395/rotating-per-packets-receiving-by-tcpdump/39765872) question.

At first vote count was 5 and after me clicking that, it got down to 3.

[image: image after]

I've had my answers history opened in another browser tab

[image: Image before]

And now the answer does not appear in the top because of vote loss.
[image: Gone]

[image: There were 5 upvotes initially]

Is this a bug or am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: IIRC, this happens when the votes were invalidated and reversed (like what happens when the serial voting script runs). There's a caching period (of unknown length) and the only way to trigger the recalc is to click the "toggle vote count" button.

Comment: Maybe related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335785/serial-voting-still-showing-on-my-questions-5-days-after-incident-cache-not-cle and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333931/1743880

Comment: @Tunaki IIRC the score recalc script runs directly before the serial voting reversal script, which is what causes the discrepancies. It should be corrected the next day.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a weird bug. That answer has never had 5 votes. See the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39765872/timeline):

[image]

Comment: The timeline does not show invalidated votes. So if a user was deleted, or if voting fraud was found and corrected, it would not show in the timeline.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Not that it matters in this case, but the timeline *also* doesn't show votes that were later removed by the caster, such as after an edit.

Comment: @TinyGiant your hypothesis is also supported by the fact that my overall reputation score didn't change since the event reported by this answer. Also I indeed can see twice -10 for user removed in the history (although not clear which question those attributed to). Can you please put your comment as an answer and I'll accept that?

Comment: You have a slightly filtered  view of the timeline. It doesn't  show things  that  *logically* didn't happen (even though they did happen, and were later  undone). In this specific case, the problem is that 2 votes were nuked by the system.